# Event before reading

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I use spring batch and I have a FlatFileItemReader.

I have a  with a reader, processer and writer.

Before starting reading, I would like to do some validation, is there any event or something to do it

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `StepExecutionListener` with your validation logic in its `beforeStep` method and configure it in your step.

Note that in `beforeStep` you can access the job parameters for example via `stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters()` (if needed).